# Rmarkdown block preview in RStudio doesn't work when code is inside function

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Say I'm working with dplyr and ggplot on a r markdown file in RStudio.

If I do something like (example incomplete code to get point across)

```
new_df <- old_df %>% head(50)

ggplot(new_df, aes(x = variable1, y = variable2))
```

and run the block of code (whether using the green button, or ctrl+enter) I will get a small preview of both the new dataframe and the generated plot. This feature is incredibly useful.

But if I execute that same code wrapped in a function like so

```
myfunc <- function(){
    new_df <- old_df %>% head(50)
    ggplot(new_df, aes(x = variable1, y = variable2))
}
myfunc()
```

the preview feature no longer works. My question is: how can I wrap code into functions and still have the preview work?

What I've tried so far:

- Printing the ggplot
- Returning the plot / df

Both of these perform expected behaviors, but the preview doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue. Using `new_df <- mtcars %>% head(10)` and `ggplot(new_df, aes(hp, mpg))` gives me the same preview independent of whether I put the code inside or outside of a function.

Comment: Same here, it works for me using `mtcars` data.